# this.setState() not working properly with bound events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an easily toggleable component, here I've made a door as an example. You click the door and it opens, if you click on it again, it closes. If you click outside of the door, it will close as well.

My issue here is that in the `handleClick()` method, the `state.active` is always `false`, no matter what. Even after I set the state, it returns false when I `console.log` it. The actual `door` does get the `"active"` class assigned to it though, so why does the method not see the change?

```
export default class Door extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }

    this.close = this.close.bind(this)
    this.open = this.open.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.active == false) {
      this.open()
    } else {
      this.close()
    }
  }

  open() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.close, true)
    this.setState({active: true})
  }

  close() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.close, true)
    this.setState({active: false})
  }

  render() {

    let classes = {
      active: this.state.active ? 'active ' : '',
    }

    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={"door " + classes.active}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the container has the issue, that it's doing something that basically resets the Door component. Can you share the code from the container?

Comment: @JeffSiver It's a div. I should clarify that the state does change, but `handleClick` does not see the change.

Comment: I suspect the React Container for this component is creating a new component causing state to reset. That would explain the behavior you are seeing. And that's why I asked if you could share code from the containing React component (though I wasn't clear, sorry).

Comment: But there isn't a container.. It sits in the root. And my other components have the state changed just fine. It's just the `handleClick` that does not see the change. Nothing is causing the component to reset, and it isn't resetting either.

Comment: No. For the last time, it sits in the root. There is no component outside of it. I'm rendering it with React.DOM. I am testing one component, that's it.

Comment: I believe what is happening is that it hits open, sets the state to true, then when you click for the door to close, the domEvent fires, triggering close which sets the state to false, and then it hits open again.

Comment: @erichardson30 You should post an answer with fixed code. :)

Comment: @SebastianOlsen now that I've found the problem, figuring out how to fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop propagation:

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.state.active == false) {
      this.open()
    } else {
      this.close()
    }
  }
```

When you are trying to close the door, the handleClick is called twice. once by the div click, and then by the body click. This can be avoided by stopping the event from bubbling up when handled once.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. But indeed, that is what is happening.

Comment: Update: Adding stopPropagation to the open and close methods fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is coming from trying to log the state in `handleClick`, the active state is never going to be true in `handleClick` calling `this.close()`, that *always* happens in your "outside click" event handler you setup in `this.open`.

1. state.active starts off false
2. user clicks door

   2a. active is false so call `open()`

   2b. add event listener that sets active to false with the next click
3. user clicks anywhere

   3a. active is set to false in `close()`

   3b. if user clicked door, GOTO 2, otherwise return to default state

You can see that the active state is in fact set to true by proxying the `setState` method.

```js
class Door extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  setState(state) {
     console.log("Setting state: ", state);
     super.setState(state);
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.active == false) {
      this.open()
    } else {
      this.close()
    }
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ active: true });
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.close, true)
  }

  close(event) {
    this.setState({active: false});
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.close, true)
  }

  render() {
    let classes = {
      active: this.state.active ? 'active ' : '',
    }

    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={"door " + classes.active}>
      </div>
    )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Door />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.door {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that it hits open, sets the state to true, then when you click for the door to close, the domEvent fires, triggering close which sets the state to false, and then it hits open again.

put the div you currently have inside another div and add the event to that outside div.

```
open() {
    var el = document.getElementById('outsideDiv');
    el.addEventListener('click', this.close, false)
    this.setState({active: true})
  }

  close() {
    var el = document.getElementById('outsideDiv');
    el.removeEventListener('click', this.close, false)
    this.setState({active: false})
  }

  render() {
    let classes = {
      active: this.state.active ? 'active ' : '',
    }

    return (
        <div id="outsideDiv">
          <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={"door " + classes.active}>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

this way it doesn't register the click when you are clicking the door.